# Is there a way to print a message every time a "chunk" gets written to a SQL database?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, chunks, pandas-to-sql

So I have a huge data frame that I am writing to a table in a SQL database by splitting the data frame into chunks of size 10,000 (I was told that speeds up the process). I use the following code:

```
   from sqlalchemy import create_engine

   my_username = 'John_Doe'
   my_password = 'fake_password'
   my_hostname = 'something_long'
   my_database = 'generic_db_name'
   my_schema = 'i_forget'

   my_engine = create_engine('postgresql://'+ my_username + ':' + my_password + '@' + my_hostname + 
   ':' +'5432/' + my_database)

   my_df.to_sql('this_is_what_im_naming_the_tbl', con = my_engine, schema='my_schema', if_exists = 'replace', 
   index = False, chunksize = 10000)
```

Would there be a way to print a message whenever a new chunk gets written into the table? Maybe something like "a chunk was just added to the table". It's a postgresql database but that information probably doesn't help.

Comment: if you use python-postgresql client like Psycopg to do the database execution,you can return the generated ID back after inserting the row.

Comment: @Rajith_Thennakoon I'm familiar with psycopg for reading from sql tables but not for writing into tables.  Do you happen to know the code that needs to be executed?